# jquery connect oop function?

Tags: php, jquery, oop

classvalidation.php

```
<?php
class Validation{

public function __construct(){
    $this->ajax_livecheck();
}

public function ajax_livecheck(){
   // this connection have no problem i had the data if i load this.
   //checking the mysql database for existed data
}

}
$Validation = new Validation();
?>
```

register.php

```
jquery-1.9.0.min.js

<script>
    //live validation name jquery
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reg-username").keyup(function (e) {

                //removes spaces from username
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

                var username = $(this).val();
                if(username.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

                if(username.length >= 4){
                    $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />'); 

                    //if i am not using oop style it work , how should i connect this to oop?
                    $.post('/class/classvalidation.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {

                      $("#user-result").html(data);
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" name="username" id="reg-username"  placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"/><br>
<span id="user-result"></span>
```

this is a live name check validation , so basically it checked the database if any name exits.

if i use normal php style , this code work. after i had changed to oop style it fail, i cant figure out how to connect with the jquery.

is anything like `$.post("<? $Validation->ajax_livecheck(); ?>")` something like to connect to the function ?

Comment: any error you got from console?

Comment: nope but the live validation keep showing the ajax loader image

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Validation {    
   public function ajax_livecheck(array $data){
      if ( ! isset($data['username']) {
         return false;          
      }

      if ( $exists_in_database) {
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }
}
$Validation = new Validation();
$result = $Validation->ajax_livecheck($_POST);

echo json_encode(array(
   'username_is_valid' => $result
));
?>
```

Then you can check in your javascript the result and do what ever you have to do.

Comment: this is a very bad oops design

Comment: It's to bring him on the right track and not to write him an validation framework

Comment: but why , you are really giving OP a bad oops design at first place.

Comment: I used the class structure that was given. The goal is to validate if the given username is valid and not already exists in the database. It seems like op is new to object oriented programming so there is no need to over complicate things. Btw it is just oop and not oops

Comment: True mate , my bad "oop" :P

Comment: thank for helping but i think is not the problem on my oop , is how i set the jquery ? thank you guys.

Comment: is like the jquery never connect to the oop function.

Comment: You have to make sure that the file is accessible from the browser. If your websever is reachable under 127.0.0.1. then for example 127.0.0,1/class/classvalidation.php should not return a 404